# Checkbox checked not updating on delete, its updating the second time

Tags: angularjs

i have a code like this:

```
 <body ng-app="UserManagement" ng-controller="UserManagementController">

        <h3>to do</h3>

        <form ng-submit="addtodo();">

            <table>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employees.todo" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{{remng()}} of {{actuallength}} remaining</td></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">

                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="emp.todo" /></td>
                     <td>{{emp.name}}</td>

                </tr>

                 <tr>

                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="addemp" /></td>
                     <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addemps()"/></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>


                     <td><input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteemps();"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
```

here i am making simple add, delete operation of a list of employees. In the delete operation, when i click delete without checking any checkbox, the items with existing checked checkboxes are deleted, but when i click any checkbox and press delete, the clicked checkbox is not deleted this time, but when i click delete second time, it deletes.

Js code:

```
    var app = angular.module("UserManagement", []);

            //Controller Part
            app.controller("UserManagementController", function($scope, $http) {
         $scope.employees = [
         {name:'Abhinav',todo:true},
         {name:'Amit', todo:false},
         {name:'Raghav',todo:true},
         {name:'Sumit', todo:false},
         {name:'Ashwani',todo:true},
         {name:'Mihir', todo:false},
         ]

        $scope.totalsel = $scope.employees.length;
         $scope.actuallength = $scope.totalsel;
         alert($scope.actuallength);
         //$scope.addtodo = function(){}
         //alert("ddd");



         $scope.deleteemps = function(){
         //alert($scope.employees.name);

         $scope.deleted_emps = [];
            //alert("in foreach: "+$scope.employees[2].todo);       
        angular.forEach($scope.employees, function(todos, index) {
         //alert(todos.todo);
        //alert(todos.name);
         if(todos.todo){


        // alert(index)
         var deletednames = todos.name;
        // var deletedtodo = todos.todo;
         //$scope.deleted_emps.push(deletednames)
        // alert(deletednames);
         $scope.deleted_emps.push({name:todos.name, todo:todos.todo});
         //var abc=angular.toJson($scope.deleted_emps);
        // alert(index);
         //console.log(angular.toJson(todos.name));
         console.log("hiii: "+$scope.deleted_emps.name);


         var indx;
for (var i=0; i<$scope.deleted_emps.length; i++) {
console.log("iii: "+$scope.deleted_emps[i].name);
console.log("i: "+$scope.employees[index].name);
//console.log($scope.employees[index].name.indexOf($scope.deleted_emps[i].name));
    indx = $scope.employees[index].name.indexOf($scope.deleted_emps[i].name);
   // alert(indx);
    if (indx > -1) {
  // alert(indx);
    //$scope.employees.splice()
       $scope.employees.splice(index, 1);
    }

}


         /* var indx;
for (var i=0; i<array2.$scope.deleted_emp; i++) {
    indx = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
    if (indx > -1) {
        array1.splice(indx, 1);
    }
}
         */

         }
         $scope.actuallength = $scope.totalsel;
         })
         }


            });
```

I am using angular js 1.6.1 . Thanks in advance.

Comment: here don't add your entire code. just put only delete function

Comment: ok, i have added the delete function only.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle based on your codes.

[Add and Delete Employees](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/kaofqsqr/3/)

Sample code of mine is like this.

```
$scope.deleteEmp = function(){
    var slicedEmps = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.employees, function(e){
        if(!e.isChecked){
            slicedEmps.push(e);
        }
    });
    $scope.employees = slicedEmps;
};
```

What I suggested is making new array instead of using 'splice'.

I hope this fiddle can help you. :)